# Authentication redirects fail

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-routing, laravel-5

when I login with wrong credentials I got the right response.
when I login with the right credentials the login page reload with 302 request
but it never redirect to statistics page.
when I debug it I found that the code goes to this authinticate.php in the middleware folder, 
it redirect to the guest login state

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }
```

**see the code:-**

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@index');
Route::post('signin', 'LoginController@signin');
Route::get('signout', 'LoginController@signout');


Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', 'StatisticsController@index');
    Route::get('/statistics', 'StatisticsController@statistics');

});
```

**Login Controller**

```
    public function index() {

        return view('login');
    }

    public function signin(Request $request) {

        $errors = [];
        $email=$request['email'];
        $password= $request['password'];
        $credentials = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
          return redirect('/statistics');


        }
        return "bad request";

    }
     public function signout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');    }

}
```

**Statistics Controller**

```
class StatisticsController extends Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
                    $this->middleware('auth');

    }
    public function index() {

    return view('statistics')->with($data);
  }

public function statistics() {
        return view('statistics');

  }



}
```

**Kernal.php** note that there is JWT auth library I use it for restful authentication with the mobile app only.

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken',
        'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken'
    ];
```

**middleware/authenticate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is everything else a stock Laravel 5.2 app? Is `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` untouched? What about the controllers in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`?

Can you also clean up your English in your question? Just add some punctuation at least -- it's hard to follow where one scenario ends and the next begins.

Comment: question is unclear!

Comment: can you show me the \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate file ??

Comment: @tremby everything related yes is stock. I have also added to the question the middleware/authinticate.php, and about the controllers in Auth folder it is the stock auth controllers, I didn't even touched it, sorry for the missing punctuation, I have edited the question
thanks for your reply

Comment: @CanCelik check it now again sorry :)

Comment: @NadimulDeCj I have included it, check it, thanks

Comment: I have double checked your code.  But whre do you specify your auth guard

Comment: @ShadyAtef in a function called handle in Middleware/Authinticate.php
it is a laravel factory function, I didn't even edited it

Comment: Are logging in through an api or web

Comment: @oseintow web via form post action

Comment: @HeshamWatany would you post the project -at least the login related & a test controller -  files on github, I will try to debug it on my own machine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your cache.I had a similar problem, where I lost a couple of hours, so these where some of the steps I've made:

- php artisan route:clear
- clear browser cache
- run composer update
- Download a fresh copy of laravel(new project), and then slowly merge chunks of your code into the new project

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Analysis:**
There's no problem with your Authentication method, or your controllers.
The problem lies with the fact that you don't have a route for "*/statistics*"
And with Laravel at-least starting version 5, you have to be explicit about your routes "PS: they deprecated Route::Controller()"
By the way 
`Route::get('/', 'StatisticsController@index');`
Refers to your application base route

**Solution**
Add the statistics route

```
Route::get('/statistics', 'StatisticsController@statistics');
```

For example.

Comment: It was there but I forgot to put it here as there is many routes in the project
anyway it is still not working, redirecting to login
I have been trying for hours
Thanks for your answer anyway man

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to StatisticsController@statistics but there is no statistics function defined in your StatisticsController.

Comment: there is a method in the controller with this name, the problem happens in the construct method, Auth becomes guest when redirected